# Python: set variables from environment and retrieve them by name

Tags: python

I'm setting some environment variables like `env['c'] = 4.0`.

There's a few of them, so `env` prints `{'c': 4.0, 'b': 2.0}`.

I need to write an eval function in my `Variable` class that sets `c` as `4.0` and `b` as `2.0`. Like, whatever the key is it should be set to a variable with its corresponding value in `eval`.

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Var('+self.name+')'

    __repr__ = __str__

    def eval(self, env):
        print 'ENV'
        print env
        for k, v in env:
            vars()[k] = v
        return self.name # to variable?
```

Also, my `k`/`v` loop doesn't work with only one element, it seems. Not sure why that is. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Here's my console output:

```
ENV
{}
a
ENV
{'b': 2.0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cdrum/cal.py", line 219, in <module>
    print testEval()
  File "/Users/cdrum/cal.py", line 205, in testEval
    print Variable('b').eval(env)
  File "/Users/cdrum/cal.py", line 86, in eval
    for k, v in env:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

**Update**

```
env = {}
env['b'] = 2.0
print Variable('b').eval(env)
```

That should return `2.0`.

Comment: unrelated, but you don't need `__str__`; in your case `__repr__` makes more sense. `str()` uses `__repr__` if there's no `__str__` method

Comment: Besides that, your question is pretty confusing. Are you trying to set variables in the scope of the *caller*? If yes, luckily that's not possible. As for the iteration, you forgot `.iteritems()` (or `.items()` in py3)

Comment: Also, `vars()[..] = ..` usually indicates you are trying to do something you shouldn't be doing (same for globals/locals instead of vars)

Comment: `for k, v in env` should probably be `for k, v in env.items()`

Comment: Yeah, I can see that it's confusing. I'm in python 2.6.x. I'll update the question with a bit more information. Thanks.

Comment: when you say environment, what do you mean? [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) or python scope/namespace?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that environment is the right word—maybe like an attribute called `eval` of `Variable('b')` that returns `2.0`. That, of course, was set in `eval` like shown in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just answered my own question with this:

```
def eval(self, env):
    return env.get(self.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is simply (as already noticed in comments) the line

```
for k,v in env:
```

A dict can be used as an iterator, but it only iterates over its **keys**. That what the error message: `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` means: you expect 2 values (a key and its value) and only get one (the key).

What you need is:

```
for k,v in env.iteritems():
    ...
```